How can I choose the resistance value in a limiter circuit?
Problem: A signal must be limited at +/- 100 mV. Assume constant-voltage model for the diodes where V_D,on = 800 mV. Design the required limiting circuit.
Attempt:

I set V_D,on + V2 (but was flipped in the problem) = +100 mV so V2 = -700mV (I changed its polarity in the simulation rather than writing '-700m'). Similarly for V3.
Now, say I choose R1 = 100 ohm, then the 'limiting' is +/- 35 mV, not 100 mV.
Moreover, if R1 = 1 ohm, the 'limiting' is +/- 150 mV (Exceeding 100mV!)
Also it depends on V1. So I suspect there is a relation between V1 and R so that I can choose the desired R value?
(Trial and error gives R ~= 8 ohm, but I am looking for a more general method for it, as the textbook I am using does not mention anything about R1).
To clarify, if R = 8 ohm, it gives approximately the correct output:

So is there a general method to determine the resistance value to satisify the requirements?

The resistor is just there to limit the current, it’s value won’t be critical unless you have a load on Vout.
If you are getting different voltages for different resistances then your diode model isn’t a constant 800 mV model, their voltage is changing with current. You need to come up with a model that fills the constant voltage requirement.
Update:
Here's the circuit with an ideal diode model where Vfwd is set to 800 mV. Works pretty much perfectly with any reasonable value resistance (although when I tried 1 MΩ it ran really slow). All you have to do is add a .op with the model, then ctrl-right click the diodes and make Value the same name as the model.

The minimum resistance for R1 has to be such that a voltage divider of it and the load will give at least the required output voltage from the given input voltage, so for example you have a \$2~V_{pk}\$ signal and you want it to clip at \$100~mV\$ so the highest the divider ratio can be is
$$
\frac{2V}{100mV} = 20
$$
so 20:1. If your load was 100 Ω you would then want the total resistance to be no more than 20 times that, so R1 could be 1900 Ω at most before it starts attenuating the signal to below 100 mV.

This circuit actually works (using the constant-voltage model) if I choose the correct "R1" , my problem is how to choose R1?. There is no load yet, I am investigating the input-output characterisitics so far.
I will edit the question to show more clearly what is required.

Thanks! That makes a lot of sense!

The resistor more or less sets the output impedance of your circuit. You need to know the load that you are feeding into. From that, you can assess the effect on the actual signal delivered to the load.
Not that for a full analysis, you ought really to know the source resistance of V1 as well.
Also note that with real diodes, choosing a higher resistor will reduce their forward current, which will in turn increase the actual voltage on their cathode. This may or may not be important, depending on your application.
Without these details in place, it is not really possible to suggest an actual value.

Assume the voltage source is ideal (I.e. no internal resistance).
Now I kinda see why I need the load as you and @GodJihyo said. But, I am wondering how does the simulator decide the values in the graph I show? Why when R1 = 100, it gives +35mV and when R1 ~=8 it gives ~100mV? Is there a formula?

yes there are formulas for the VI curve of a diode. if you search you will find. It depends on the diode you are using in your model, I think.
